# Gradient computation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, mathematics

I'm working with some math-heavy code in JavaScript. I just realized that there's a render that currently takes about 30 minutes. 95% of that time is spent in a single ~40 line function that I've pasted below. I am not extremely well-versed in JavaScript math optimization, so my first attempts to optimize this code haven't gone wonderfully.

I would love any pointers as to what in here is slowing things down. I have good reason to believe that things are non-optimal because the same code in Python runs about 30x faster and JS is not a slow language.

```
// return cost and gradient, given an arrangement
costGrad: function(Y) {
  var N = this.N; // About 5000 long
  var dim = this.dim; // About 300 long
  var P = this.P; // About 5000^2 long

  var pmul = this.iter < 100 ? 4 : 1; // trick that helps with local optima

  // compute current Q distribution, unnormalized first
  var Qu = zeros(N * N);
  var qsum = 0.0;
  for(var i=0;i<N;i++) {
    for(var j=i+1;j<N;j++) {
      var dsum = 0.0;
      for(var d=0;d<dim;d++) {
        var dhere = Y[i][d] - Y[j][d];
        dsum += dhere * dhere;
      }
      var qu = 1.0 / (1.0 + dsum); // Student t-distribution
      Qu[i*N+j] = qu;
      Qu[j*N+i] = qu;
      qsum += 2 * qu;
    }
  }
  // normalize Q distribution to sum to 1
  var NN = N*N;
  var Q = zeros(NN);
  for(var q=0;q<NN;q++) { Q[q] = Math.max(Qu[q] / qsum, 1e-100); }

  var cost = 0.0;
  var grad = [];
  for(var i=0;i<N;i++) {
    var gsum = new Array(dim); // init grad for point i
    for(var d=0;d<dim;d++) { gsum[d] = 0.0; }
    for(var j=0;j<N;j++) {
      cost += - P[i*N+j] * Math.log(Q[i*N+j]); // accumulate cost (the non-constant portion at least...)
      var premult = 4 * (pmul * P[i*N+j] - Q[i*N+j]) * Qu[i*N+j];
      for(var d=0;d<dim;d++) {
        gsum[d] += premult * (Y[i][d] - Y[j][d]);
      }
    }
    grad.push(gsum);
  }

  return {cost: cost, grad: grad};
}
```

For those that are curious to see more, this is from the wonderful [tsnejs library from Andrej Karpathy](https://github.com/karpathy/tsnejs).

Comment: On Chrome `v = Math.max(v1,v)` is slower than `v = v1 > v ? v1 : v;` You should use literal array declaration, set length for size, and use fill to init.  `gsum =[]; gsum.length=dim; gsum.fill(0)` You do i*N+j to index many time inside loop. In outer loop `var iN=i*N;` in inner loop `var iNJ = iN+j`  then index using iNJ. Not much else to do maybe typed arrays. Firefox is currently much faster than Chrome, also you can uses webWorkers as it looks like it can be done concurrently.. But javscript is still slow Python 30x is about right

Comment: Could you make an running example with maybe around 500 instead of 5000 to test how to optimize it?

Comment: @Blindman67 implemented everything, and the max replacement got me a ~15% speed improvement, but all the other changes were unfortunately negligible. Why do you say that 30x python is about right? Javascript is typically much faster than python, even hitting only 2-3x of C for many tasks.

I'm guessing this is just that JS is a bad fit for matrix math? I'm having trouble finding good matrix math benchmarks across language though. Any resources?

Comment: @juvian Unfortunately changing the size by an order of magnitude would invalidate any results from optimization since dim and N scale at different rates. If the two are comparable it's almost certain that the limiting areas of code will change.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Been a long time since I used Python, and having quick look around the web seems JS has caught up with it, well at least NodeJs running V8. SO I will retract the last sentence of my previous comment. BTW you could use the GPU via webGL there are a few libs on github that provide interfaces to the GPU for this type of  processing using Javascript.

Comment: @Blindman67 for some reason all of the webGL libraries I find have very strange restrictions on things like array size, things like not supporting anything larger than a 4x4 matrix, is there a good example of one for which that's not an issue?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Of the top of my head i think WebMonkeys may do it for you. But you can always write the code yourself, though webGL does not support doubles at the moment (I think) so you will have to do it as 32bit floats

Comment: @SlaterTyranus well, you should try running chrome profiler to see what part of the function is slowing things down. If its the zeros function, maybe asking so much memory is too slow and you can fix that reusing arrays, but if that´s caused by the N * N * dim fors, no way around that

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Anothing thing you might consider is web assembly

Comment: @SlaterTyranus just tried running the function with N = 1000 (don´t have enough memory for 5000) and it takes a few seconds, are you sure a single run of that function takes several minutes?

Comment: @juvian the problem is that it's not a single run, this function has to be called hundreds of times. 500-1000 in a typical run.

Comment: @juvian also, I've used the chrome profiler, unfortunately it doesn't give any information about called built-in functions. The only external functions taking up significant resources are the Math.log, and Math.max calls. Zeros takes about 2-5% of total time. Maybe worth improving in the future, but probably not a first step.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus you can use things like console.time and console.timeEnd to try to check which part is most time consuming. In the test I made, the second part of the algorithm takes about 3 times more than first one. How does the data change between the iterations? Maybe something can stay precalculated?

Comment: I think we could use a little more context. Could you edit your question to provide us insight into the structure of the `Y` parameter and show us the`zeros()` function?

Comment: @Thriggle you can view the zeros function in the link provided

Comment: @juvian, According to the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), supporting but non-essential code can be linked from other sites, but any code to be reviewed is better embedded in the question itself. Even if it isn't up for review, it wouldn't *hurt* to embed it, if only to show people like me (i.e. people too lazy to click links) the shape of the method's return value.